# Get Sum of the Count column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to display on top of the page total no of critical items and below the list. This is my query

```
SELECT  vs.vessel_name, vs.CallSign ,COUNT(IF(m.AvailableQuant <= m.MinQuant,1, NULL)) AS 'Critical'                
FROM tbl_vesselmaster vs
INNER JOIN comp_login cl ON vs.co_id = cl.id
INNER JOIN m_shipinv m ON vs.id = m.ShipId
WHERE vs.co_id=123
GROUP BY vs.id, vs.vessel_name ;
```

this is the output

```
vessel_name  CallSign  Critical_Items  
-----------  --------  ----------------
Sima Sadaf   (NULL)                   4
sdare        3q1                      1
```

I want to display on top of the page the total no of critical items i.e 5 items are critical
how do i get the sum?

Comment: make the sum in your php script. Not in sql.

Comment: @Jens this is not a column from database. How can it be done in php. Can u explain it with code

Comment: You should count the values of `Critical` in your php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will return you the sum of critical items :

```
SELECT  SUM(IF(m.AvailableQuant <= m.MinQuant,1, 0)) as total FROM tbl_vesselmaster vs
    INNER JOIN comp_login cl ON vs.co_id = cl.id
    INNER JOIN m_shipinv m ON vs.id = m.ShipId
    WHERE vs.co_id=123;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COUNT(IF(m.AvailableQuant <= m.MinQuant,1, NULL)) AS 'Critical'                
FROM tbl_vesselmaster vs
INNER JOIN comp_login cl ON vs.co_id = cl.id
INNER JOIN m_shipinv m ON vs.id = m.ShipId
WHERE vs.co_id=123
```

should give you **all** critical item

Answer (score 0):

I hope You just want total in your existing query..

```
select sum(Critical) as Total from(
SELECT  vs.vessel_name, vs.CallSign ,COUNT(IF(m.AvailableQuant <= m.MinQuant,1, NULL)) AS Critical                
FROM tbl_vesselmaster vs
INNER JOIN comp_login cl ON vs.co_id = cl.id
INNER JOIN m_shipinv m ON vs.id = m.ShipId
WHERE vs.co_id=123
GROUP BY vs.id, vs.vessel_name )alias;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this ?

```
select sum(d.Critical) from (SELECT  vs.vessel_name, vs.CallSign ,COUNT(IF(m.AvailableQuant <= m.MinQuant,1, NULL)) AS 'Critical'                
FROM tbl_vesselmaster vs
INNER JOIN comp_login cl ON vs.co_id = cl.id
INNER JOIN m_shipinv m ON vs.id = m.ShipId
WHERE vs.co_id=123
GROUP BY vs.id, vs.vessel_name )d
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an extra total line by using WITH ROLLUP. Then make sure to get this first and display null for the call sign:

```
SELECT 
  vessel_name, 
  case when vessel_name is not null then CallSign end as CallSign, 
  Critical
FROM
(
  SELECT
    vs.vessel_name, 
    vs.CallSign,
    SUM(m.AvailableQuant <= m.MinQuant) AS Critical
  FROM tbl_vesselmaster vs
  INNER JOIN comp_login cl ON vs.co_id = cl.id
  INNER JOIN m_shipinv m ON vs.id = m.ShipId
  WHERE vs.co_id=123
  GROUP BY vs.id WITH ROLLUP
) AS vessels
ORDER BY (vessel_name IS NOT NULL), vessel_name;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Oh yes, that is true. MySQL (as most dbms) requires a name for the derived table. I'll edit right now.

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NOT NULL vessel_name), vessel_name LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 17

Comment: Yes, a typo. `IS NOT NULL vessel_name` must be `IS NOT NULL vessel_name` of course. I am a little surprised however that you post this here instead of simply correcting the errors. First message was the derived table needs an alias, so give it an alias. Next message is a syntax error at `IS NOT NULL vessel_name`, which is quite obvious. So just correct it.